# Finding the max of Zoo object in R

Tags: r, max, zoo

I have z - zoo object of time series. Its `str` description is:

```
> str (z)
‘zoo’ series from 2014-11-26 13:00:00 to 2015-03-01
  Data: Named num [1:2152] 0 0.07 0.07 0.05 0.06 0.02 0.04 0.02 0.02 0.01 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2152] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  Index:  POSIXct[1:2152], format: "2014-11-26 13:00:00" "2014-11-26 14:00:00" "2014-11-26 15:00:00" "2014-11-26 16:00:00" ..
```

I would like to find the maximum values in the series:

```
> which.max(z)
272 
272
```

I get twice the same number 272. I think it is because of the `- attr(*, "names")`
When I use the following:

```
> mx <- z[which.max(z)]
> mx
2014-12-07 20:00:00 
                0.1 
> coredata(mx)
272 
0.1
```

I would like to get just the value of `0.1` instead of `272` and `0.1`

Comment: Try `unname(coredata(mx))`

Comment: Thanks Pierre! Please add it as answer for the credit. You will be praised for adding explanation.

Comment: Feel free to add answer. Your effort will be praised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pierre Lafortune
The solution is:

```
> unname(coredata(mx))
[1] 0.1
```